# Generating SQl Grammar exception while inserting data into table

Tags: java, hibernate

Hi guys I'm new to hibernate. I was learning *one2many* and here is the program.
My program has 1 main class, 1 cfg file and 1 hbm file. The problem is when I'm inserting data into my table *state* and *city* it's generating the sql_queries but after that it's also generating an exception which blocks the data to be updated in database.

**Config.cfg.xml**

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<!--
To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hibernate</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">ankita</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.autocommit">false</property>
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="format_sql">true</property>
    <property name="use_sql_comments">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.transaction.factory_class">org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransactionFactory</property>
    <mapping resource="resources/State.hbm.xml"/>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

**State.hbm.xml**

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="onetomany.States" table="stat">
        <id name="name" column="name" type="string">
            <generator class="assigned"></generator>
        </id>

        <property name="id" column="id" type="integer"></property>
        <list name="city" table="city" cascade="none" lazy="true">
            <key column="state"></key>
            <list-index base="0" column="index"></list-index>
            <one-to-many class="onetomany.Cities"></one-to-many>
        </list>
    </class>

    <class name="onetomany.Cities" table="city">
        <id name="id" column="id" type="integer">
            <generator class="increment"></generator>
        </id>

        <property name="name" column="name" type="string"></property>
    </class>

</hibernate-mapping>
```

**Main Class**

```
    /*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package onetomany;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

/**
 *
 * @author ankita mohanty
 */
public class Insert {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Configuration cfg= new Configuration();
        cfg.configure("/resources/Config.cfg.xml");
        SessionFactory sf= cfg.buildSessionFactory();
        Session s= sf.openSession();
        Transaction tx= (Transaction) s.beginTransaction();

        States st= new States();
        st.setId(1);
        st.setName("Odisha");

        Cities ct= new Cities();
        ct.setName("Jajpur");
        Cities ct1= new Cities();
        ct1.setName("Bhadrak");
        Cities ct2= new Cities();
        ct2.setName("Jharsuguda");
        Cities ct3= new Cities();
        ct3.setName("Sambalpur");
        Cities ct4= new Cities();
        ct4.setName("Bhubaneswar");

        List<Cities> list= new ArrayList<Cities>();
        list.add(ct);
        list.add(ct1);
        list.add(ct3);
        list.add(ct4);

        st.setCity(list);
        s.save(st);
        s.save(ct);
        s.save(ct1);
        s.save(ct2);
        s.save(ct3);
        s.save(ct4);
        tx.commit();
        s.close();



    }
}
```

**My Table**

**(1)stat**--------id
                |--name(PK)


**(2)city**--------id(PK)
                |--name
                |--state(FK)
                |--index(Index of List)

**Exception**

```
org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: Could not execute JDBC batch update
at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:92)
at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:275)
at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:262)
at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:182)
at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:321)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:51)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1206)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:375)
at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.commit(JDBCTransaction.java:137)
at onetomany.Insert.main(Insert.java:55)<br>
Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'index=3 where id=5' at line 1
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeBatchSerially(PreparedStatement.java:2054)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeBatch(PreparedStatement.java:1467)
at org.hibernate.jdbc.BatchingBatcher.doExecuteBatch(BatchingBatcher.java:70)
at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:268)
... 8 more
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'index=3 where id=5' at line 1
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1053)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4120)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4052)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2503)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2664)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2794)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2155)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2458)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeBatchSerially(PreparedStatement.java:2006)
... 11 more
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`index` is [a reserved mysql keyword](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html#keywords-5-7-detailed-I), that's probably the issue here, seing the error message.

To fix the issue, you should rename the column. Maybe you could prefix column name with the table name like `city_index` etc

Comment: Thanks bro it's solved thanks for the pointing issue was with index

Answer (score 1):

You are using reserved MySql keyword `"index"`. To solve this problem you could rename the column name or use reserved keywords escape method. 
If you don't want to rename it, in .hbm.xml you should enclose the keyword with square brackets `column="[index]"` or use single quote to enclose the double quotes `column='"index"'`. If you will use reserved keyword in class annotation you also should enclose the keyword with square brackets `name="[index]"` or use double quotes to enclose it `name="\"index\""`.

These methods allows to use sql reserved keywords.

I hope it helps and become useful in the future...